# Access model from controller in ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have a simple application with a model, route and controller. I can't access the data from the model in my controller. I use ember-cli so I have the following structure:

**/app/router.js**

```
var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType
});
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('logs',{path: '/'});
});
export default Router;
```

**/app/routes/logs.js**

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  controllerName: 'logs',
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('logs');
  }
});
```

**/app/models/logs.js**

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  ip: DS.attr('string'),
  timestamp: DS.attr('number'),
  visited_resource: DS.attr('string'),
  pretty_string: DS.attr('string')
});
```

**/app/controllers/logs.js**

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  url: function() {
    var model = this.get('model');
    var basePath = "http://example.com";
    var path = model.visited_resource;
    return basePath+path
  }.property('visited_resource')
});
```

My problem is that the `model.visited_resources`, or `this.get('model.visited_resources')` or `this.get('model.[any param]')` is undefined.

If I log the whole model object and inspect it, all my data is there!
! https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkvyT.png

It's just that the controller can't access it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your model is an array thus your logs controller should be extended from `ArrayController` and every thing will fall into place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your model is an array from looking at that screenshot (*`content: Array[5]`*), so you need to get the first object if you want a single item:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  url: Ember.computed('model', function() {
    var logs = this.get('model');
    var firstLog = logs.get('firstObject');
    var path = firstLog.get('visited_resource');
    var basePath = 'http://example.com';
    return basePath + path; 
  });
});
```

or iterate over each item and return an array:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  urls: Ember.computed('model', function() {
    var logs = this.get('model');
    var basePath = 'http://example.com';
    var urls = logs.map(function(model) {
      var path = model.get('visited_resource');
      return basePath + path;
    });
    return urls;
   })
});
```

To create a computed property on the model, then do it on the model:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  ip: DS.attr('string'),
  timestamp: DS.attr('number'),
  visited_resource: DS.attr('string'),
  pretty_string: DS.attr('string'),
  url: Ember.computed('visited_resource', function() {
    var basePath = 'http://example.com';
    var path = this.get('visited_resource');
    return basePath + path;
  })
});
```

and you'll be to access the `url` property like any other property:

```
   export default Ember.Controller.extend({
      url: Ember.computed('model', function() {
        var logs = this.get('model');
        var firstLog = logs.get('firstObject');
        return firstLog.get('url');
      })
    })
```

You can also explicitly set the model using `setupController`:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  controllerName: 'logs',
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('logs');
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('model', model);

    // or first item only
    controller.set('model', model.get('firstObject'));
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I totally thought wrong about how it worked. I changed it to become an ArrayController instead. I'm now trying to make the whole ObjectController thingy work. Thanks again!

Comment: @FilipNilsson ObjectController and ArrayController are going to become Deprecated. Use just Controller. http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_objectcontroller